# How to correctly truncate integral types

Tags: c++

I've asked a similar question but after more research I came across something I cannot understand, and hopefully someone can explain what's causing this behavior:

```
// We wish to store a integral type, in this case 2 bytes long.
signed short Short = -390;

// In this case, signed short is required to be 2 bytes:
assert(sizeof(Short) == 2);

cout << "Short: " << Short << endl; // output: -390

signed long long Long = Short;

// in this case, signed long long is required to be 8 bytes long
assert(sizeof(Long) == 8);

cout << "Long: " << Long << endl; // output: -390

// enough bytes to store the signed short:
unsigned char Bytes[sizeof(Short)];

// Store Long in the byte array:
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(Short); ++i)
    Bytes[i] = (Long >> (i * 8)) & 0xff;

// Read the value from the byte array:
signed long long Long2 = (Bytes[0] << 0) + (Bytes[1] << 8);

cout << Long2 << endl; // output: 65146

signed short Short2 = static_cast<signed short>(Long2);

cout << Short2 << endl; // output: -390
```

output:

```
-390
-390
65146
-390
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? Is this undefined behavior? Why?

Comment: Formally, the behavior of your program is unspecified (at best, and possibly undefined), as it relies on the exact representation of integers, which is an implementation detail. Practically speaking, assuming the typical two's complement representation, you are losing sign extension: `Long2` has zeros in high-order bytes where `Long` has `0xFF`s

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The reason I'm storing the integers this way is, I read somewhere it's the way to safely do so. I guess that source wasn't great? Could you elaborate on how to properly store integers into a byte array? Or do I need to define my own format?

Comment: `Long >> 8`, with `Long` negative, is implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Well, it worked - you got back the same `short` value that you started with. The fact that you got a different `long long` value is not exactly surprising, seeing as you've only stored two bytes out of eight, therefore losing information. Why are you going through `long long` anyway - why not from `short` to a byte array and back to `short` directly?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm trying to save arbitrary integral types to an array, using as little bytes as possible. I set it up as a template function with parameters that let me calculate the number of bytes needed, so when I read them I know the number of bytes used to store it - so I could read as short at that moment when NumBytes == 2, but I wanted to do it in a more general way. Also I'm not sure how to read it when NumBytes == 3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to do with the way negative numbers are stored.  A negative number will begin with a `1` in its binary format.

```
signed long long Long = Short;
```

This is automatically doing a conversion for you.  It isn't just assigning bits from one to the other, it is converting the value resulting in your 64-bit value starting with a `1` to indicate negative, and the rest denoting the 390 in 2s complement (can't be bothered working all the bits out).

```
signed long long Long2 = (Bytes[0] << 0) + (Bytes[1] << 8);
```

Now you're only retrieving the end two bytes, which will just represent the 390 magnitude.  Your first two bytes will be zeros, so it thinks it is a positive number.  It should work out as 2^16 - 390, and it does.

```
signed short Short2 = static_cast<signed short>(Long2);
```

This is an overflow.  65146 doesn't fit into a signed, 2-byte integer and so ends out populating the signing bit, making it get interpreted as negative.  By no co-incidence, the negative number it represents is -390.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation!